# Maven RPM plugin: Different content for CentOS 6.5 and 5.6

Tags: maven, rpm-maven-plugin

I have been using rpm-maven-plugin to generate RPMs to install on CentOS 6.5. Now I need to extend it to package an RPM with binaries compiled on CentOS 5.6. My development machine is OSX and I would like to be able to test RPM generation for CentOS 6.5 and 5.6 on it. Which means that I should be able to pass the target OS as a command line parameter. Any ideas on how to do this?

I looked through the plugin's documentation and it seems like I need to use  filter, but nowhere I can find how to determine the value for that classifier for CentOS 5.6 and 6.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating two separate maven-rpm-plugin executions: one - for CentOS 6.5 and one - for CentOS 5.6. I also disabled automatic uploading of RPMs to Maven repo during release process because the two RPMs had the same name. I disabled uploading by adding -Dmaven.deploy.skip=true to maven-release-plugin  section.

Here is a relevant excerpt from my pom.xml (can be executed with `mvn package`):

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>-Dmaven.deploy.skip=true</arguments>
                    <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                    <!--Disable deployment at the end because CentOS 5.6 and 6.5 profile artifacts will collide-->
                    <goals></goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>CentOS-5.6</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached-rpm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>${rpmName}</name>
                        <needarch>x86_64</needarch>
                        <workarea>target/rpm/centos-5.6</workarea>
                        <group>CollectD</group>
                        <defaultDirmode>755</defaultDirmode>
                        <defaultFilemode>755</defaultFilemode>
                        <defaultUsername>root</defaultUsername>
                        <defaultGroupname>root</defaultGroupname>
                        <mappings>
                            <!-- Root directory -->
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>
                                        <location>${project.build.directory}/classes/centos-5.6/collectd</location>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>etc/*</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </source>
                                </sources>
                            </mapping>
                            <!-- Overwrite configurations with the right file permissions -->
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}/etc</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
                                <configuration>true</configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>
                                        <location>${project.build.directory}/classes/centos-5.6/collectd/etc</location>
                                    </source>
                                </sources>
                                <filemode>644</filemode>
                            </mapping>
                            <!-- local output directories for logging and so on -->
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}/var/log</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                            </mapping>
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}/var/lib</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                            </mapping>
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}/var/run</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                            </mapping>
                            <!-- collectd service startup script -->
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>/etc/init.d</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>
                                        <location>${project.build.directory}/classes/centos-common/init.d/collectd</location>
                                    </source>
                                </sources>
                            </mapping>
                        </mappings>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>CentOS-6.5</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached-rpm</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <name>${rpmName}</name>
                        <needarch>x86_64</needarch>
                        <workarea>target/rpm/centos-6.5</workarea>
                        <group>CollectD</group>
                        <defaultDirmode>755</defaultDirmode>
                        <defaultFilemode>755</defaultFilemode>
                        <defaultUsername>root</defaultUsername>
                        <defaultGroupname>root</defaultGroupname>
                        <mappings>
                            <!-- Root directory -->
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>
                                        <location>${project.build.directory}/classes/centos-6.5/collectd</location>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>etc/*</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </source>
                                </sources>
                            </mapping>
                            <!-- Overwrite configurations with the right file permissions -->
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}/etc</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
                                <configuration>true</configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>
                                        <location>${project.build.directory}/classes/centos-6.5/collectd/etc</location>
                                    </source>
                                </sources>
                                <filemode>644</filemode>
                            </mapping>
                            <!-- local output directories for logging and so on -->
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}/var/log</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                            </mapping>
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}/var/lib</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                            </mapping>
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>${installDir}/var/run</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
                            </mapping>
                            <!-- collectd service startup script -->
                            <mapping>
                                <directory>/etc/init.d</directory>
                                <directoryIncluded>false</directoryIncluded>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>
                                        <location>${project.build.directory}/classes/centos-common/init.d/collectd</location>
                                    </source>
                                </sources>
                            </mapping>
                        </mappings>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Where did you specify the targetOS ? and what values did you put into it? I'm trying to build for CentOS on Windows, and I've tried adding <targetOS>i386-linux</targetOS> to the properties XML block - but when I install it says its not intended for this OS. How can I build for CentOS7 ?

Comment: I just made sure that our Jenkins build job uploaded the RPMs to Yum repos for CentOS 6.5 and 5.6 respectively. So, in the end I wasn't able to solve this problem just with Maven.

Comment: Ah okay - cheers ! Seems to work for me if I push from windows to GIT and then clone it on CentOS and build it there! If you're still interested - a good solution we have in work is a Vagrant VM which mounts your workspace from the windows computer to a VM ! So you dont need to transfer files, just develop on Windows and then switch to the VM for building ! Once it's built - it's on the Windows computer in .m2 !

Comment: could you please post your pom section of the multiple executions. I'm trying to achieve something similiar (different service scripts for systemd and init.d (jar as a service))  but the first .rpm gets deleted with the build of the second rpm.